# ¿Cómo muestro u oculto botónes especifico según autorización en las políticas en las "acciones" del DataTables en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, datatables

Tengo una política típica que sí es el usuario que creo el registro puede editarlo o eliminarlo.

```
 public function update(User $authUser,Tabla $datos){
        return $authUser->id == $datos->iduser;
    }

   public function destroy(User $authUser, Tabla $datos){
        return $authUser->id == $datos->iduser;
    }
```

Quisiera saber cómo puedo ocultar o mostrar un icono especifico en el DataTables dentro de mis acciones si puede o no realizar esa operación el usuario. Por ejemplo no mostrarle el icono de editar(Pencil) o eliminar(tras) o ambos.

```
if(request()->ajax()){

return datatables()::of($tabla)

//COLUMNA ACCIONES
    ->addColumn('acciones', function ($data) {
       $acciones = '<div class="btn-group">

        <a href="' . url()->current() . '/' . $data->id . '" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt text-white"></i>
        </a>

       <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm eliminarDato" 
                action="' . url()->current() . '/' . $data->id . '" 
                method="DELETE" pagina="tabla" token="' . csrf_token() . '">
                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></I>
       </button>
     </div>';
        return $acciones;
    })
    ->rawColumns(['acciones'])
    ->make(true);
            }
```

Comment: ¿Ya probaste con `@can` `@endcan` para englobar que acciones puede hacer?

Comment: ¿Si, pero como lo incluyo en esta parte del código en el controlador? Lo que quiero es que si puede editar el respectivo $data->id muestre el botón y si no no lo muestre dentro del DataTables